# Why does the the Drain supply voltage for an NMOS transistor need to be greater than or equal to the overdrive voltage to ensure pinch off condition?

Tags: transistors

Still relatively new to electronics and have had this question on my mind for a while.

Comment: See if this this http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/Applying%20a%20Drain%20Voltage%20to%20an%20NMOS%20Device.pdf answers your question.

Comment: Have you had the question on your mind because it's homework?